# How to update managed metadata column with multiple values using JSOM

Tags: javascript, 2016, jsom, managed-metadata

I'm using JSOM to update a managed metadata column (in SharePoint 2016) using term GUID like this:

```
...
var oListItem = collListItem.itemAt(i)
oListItem.set_item('SPSBaranID', theTermGUID)
oListItem.update()
...
```

This is working perfectly fine, but I need to **add multiple terms to the same column**. I have all GUIDs in a JavaScript array. I tried passing the array as the second parameter inside `oListItem.set_item()` but it didn't work. Is there a method to achieve this goal? Any advice and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might help https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/update-taxonomymmd-field-via-jsom/

I've copied the code sample directly from that page.

```
function CreateItem(isSingleValue){  
 SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {  
       'use strict';  
        var context = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl);  
        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('CustomList');              
        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();  
        var item = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);  
        var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("MyMMDField");  
        var taxField = context.castTo(field, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);  
          
        if(isSingleValue == true){ // this you have to handle manually , use   
            var termValue = new SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue();  
            termValue.set_label("MyWikiTerm");  
            termValue.set_termGuid("fb58bc5e-5ce5-41fc-9a90-7431018aa935");  
            termValue.set_wssId(-1);  
            taxField.setFieldValueByValue(item, termValue);  
            item.set_item("Title", "Created New Item and Set single valued Taxonomy");  
        }  
        else { // this you have to handle manually  
            item.set_item("Title", "Created New Item and Multi valued Taxonomy");  
            var pairs = "-1;#MyWikiTerm|fb58bc5e-5ce5-41fc-9a90-7431018aa935;#-1;#MyWikiTerm2|1cee8427-41f1-4a2b-aff3-26c67685988e";  
            var termValueCollection = new SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(context,pairs,taxField);  
            taxField.setFieldValueByValueCollection(item, termValueCollection);  
        }             
        item.update();  
        context.load(item);  
        context.executeQueryAsync(  
            function () {  
                console.log('Item created sucessfully: ' + item.get_id());  
            },   
            function (sender, args) {  
              console.log("exception in addItem");  
            });  
    }, 'SP.Taxonomy.js');  
}
```

See the part that uses  `taxField.setFieldValueByValueCollection(item, termValueCollection);`